# Set default value for dict from json.loads

Tags: python, json

I want to add default value for key not exist in json.loads

I have a list of keys like this

```
["id", "name", "wkt", "created", "radius", "round"]
```

and many line json file which doesn't have enough keys like this:

```
{"id":"1", "name":"a", "round":5}   
{"id":"2", "wkt": "POINT(1.1)", "created":"2018-22-11T10:00:00"}   
{"id":"3", "radius":3}
```

Expect result:

```
{"id":"1", "name": "a", "wkt":null, "created":null, "radius":null, "round":5}
```

My current sollution

```
for line in lines:
    line_dict = json.loads(line)
    for key in keys:
        if not key in line_dict:
            line_dict[key] = None
    yield line_dict
```

Expect result

I want to find more efficient way to set default for not exist keys with json.loads. With object_hooks or object_pair_hook i had no success so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can initialise a dictionary of empty values and update accordingly.

```
keys = ["id", "name", "wkt", "created", "radius", "round"]       
default = dict.fromkeys(keys, None)

def read_json(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f: 
        for line in f:
            d = default.copy()
            d.update(json.loads(line))
            yield d
```

Comment: This forces `None` as the default value, though, but it's obviously easy to modify to e.g. copy a static dictionary as the base and then `update` it with the values from `json.loads`.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks! That makes it clearer that the default can be set easily.

Comment: You can keep it nice and use `defaultdict` from `collections` to initialise the dictionary without coding it yourself (`collections` is a standard library module, no installation required)

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding your question, but can you not do something like this?

```
def filler(d):
   for i in ["id", "name", "wkt", "created", "radius", "round"]:
     if i not in d:
       d[i] = None
   return d

json.loads('{"id":"1", "name":"a", "round":5}', object_hook=filler)
```

For me, this returns

```
{u'name': u'a', 'created': None, u'id': u'1', 'radius': None, 'wkt': None, u'round': 5}
```